# Designing with CSS

Tags: html, css

Consider the following table structure:

```
<table style="width:150px;">
 <tr>
  <td>some dynamicly generated content that can wrap several lines</td>
  <td valign="bottom"><img ... /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

How do I get this effect using CSS (i.e. that when the content in the first TD takes more lines,
 the tables grows vertically and the image "drops" to the bottom)

Comment: It would be nice if down voters would leave a comment explaining...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `display:inline-block` You'll need a small hack for older browsers (Easily google-able), but it should accomplish what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/4vYHa/

```
.content{
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.bottom-image{
     display:inline-block;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>        
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: If you then need the image to stick to the top you would just add `vertical-align:top;`:

```
.bottom-image{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution and went along with it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="maintable">

<div class="data1">some dynamicly generated content that can wrap several lines</div>
<div class="data1"><img ... /></div>
</div>
```

then apply CSS to your data1 to float left and clear left, that will keep them above each other. You can go on to add width restrictions too.

Comment: but I don't want them one below the other, the image should align its bottom with the bottom of the text but stay to its right.

Answer (score 0):

Use floated divs. Give the text div no fixed width, it will then stretch as needed and the image div will eventually "drop" below the text.

Comment: I am using floats but I cant figure out the structure you are suggesting.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/S3B3a/ for an example without floats but positioning as I think this fits your need better.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
       <div style="width:150px;">
        <div class="dynamic">some dynamicly generated content that can wrap several lines</div>
        <div style="width:20px;"><img ... /></div>
       </div>
```

**EDIT**

```
                <div style="width:150px;">
               <div style="width:100px; float:left;">some dynamicly generated content that can wrap several lines</div>
               <div style="width:50px; float:right;"><img src="test.png" /></div>
               </div>
```

**Check Jsfiddle Output:** http://jsfiddle.net/srinivasan/AhJzH/1/

Comment: sorry, the image is still "top-aligned" with the text...
Thanks for your effort though.